# add item to Spinner in diffrent layout not work

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I try to add items to Spinner in another layout but it's unsuccessful.

This is my code:

```
        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.register, null);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.snprCity);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
        List<String> list;

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("NY");
        list.add("CA");
        list.add("TX");
        list.add("CH");
        list.add("NJ");
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
```

Reg XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="1" >



    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="30dp"
                >

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="نام :"
                    android:id="@+id/tmp" android:layout_gravity="right" android:paddingTop="30px"
                    android:paddingBottom="10px"
                    />
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textColor="#ff010101"
                    android:id="@+id/edtName" android:layout_gravity="right" />
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                      android:text="نام خانوادگی: "
                      android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_gravity="right" android:paddingTop="30px"
                      android:paddingBottom="10px"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textColor="#ff010101"
                    android:id="@+id/edtFamily" android:layout_gravity="right"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="رایانامه ( ایمیل) :"
                      android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_gravity="right" android:paddingTop="30px"
                      android:paddingBottom="10px"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textColor="#ff010101"
                    android:id="@+id/edtEmail" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="شماره همراه :"
                      android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_gravity="right" android:paddingTop="30px"
                      android:paddingBottom="10px"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            />
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textColor="#ff010101"
                    android:id="@+id/edtTel" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="شهر: "
                      android:id="@+id/textView5" android:layout_gravity="right"
                      android:paddingTop="30px"
                      android:paddingBottom="10px"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/snprCity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="204dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ثبت نام"
                    android:id="@+id/btnRegiter" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:onClick="btnRegiter"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

When the code runs the `snprCity` is empty.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can the problem be in some other place? May be (sorry for a such a simple example) you inflate but don't add your view to its parent and just look at another spinner?

Comment: I found the problem but cant slove it, The `snprCity` not found.

Comment: If it isn't found at all spinner will be null and spinner.setAdapter() will cause Exception. Check for double IDs...

Comment: @sberezin I Dont have any error or Exception on this event.

Comment: may I have a look at register.xlm?

Comment: @sberezin I add it to question.

Comment: Would you provide piece of code where you handle inflatedView (add it to parent view group)

Comment: I dont understand plz say me with reference or more comment.

Comment: Well, you inflate inflatedView. You should do something with it - if it's just inflated but not attached to parent it won't be visible at all. There are 2 typical ways it's done: 1) return view from getView() method or 2) call parentViewGroup.addView(inflatedView). I'd like to understand how you do that

Comment: can you say me exactly what I do?

Comment: you: 1)inflate view 2)find spinner 3)create and fill list 4)create and initialize adapter 5)set adapter for the spinner. But I don't see what do you do with inflated view next. If you do nothing - it stays invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

```
setContentView(R.layout.register);
```

Change to :

```
setContentView(inflatedView);
```

The problem with View.

Comment: This line wasn't in your original post. So it was really about what is done with view after inflation, as I've mentioned in comment from Nov 23

Comment: @sberezin Yes I agree